# Setting date on Android in the future (Samsung S7/Android 7.0)

Tags: android, date

I am testing certificate renewals. After expiry (in future) our software should automatically connect to a server to renew the certificate.

In order to test this situation I was thinking to forward the date/time into the future on Samsang S7 running Android 7.0.

Strangely if I set the date/time to July 31, 2025 it jumps back - after a few seconds - to July 31, 2017. But if I move the date/time to August 30, 2017, then it stays.

Phone has WiFi turned off, SIM card only (mobile internet available) and "Automatic date and time" in Settings "Date and time" is turned off.

If I remove the SIM card, then I can move the date/time forward to July 31, 2015 (but then my app has no internet to renew the cert :(.

Anyone familiar with this problem? Is it a bug? From Samsung? From Android 7.0? Any suggestions for a workaround to set the date/time into the future (like 2025)?

BR, Rene

Comment: Have you tried the combination of WiFi enabled but no SIM? If the device is resetting the date/time when you have "Automatic date and time" turned off, I'd consider that to be a bug.

Comment: Yes. Turned WiFi off, because somewhere else on the internet somebody claimed that turning WiFi off would eliminate the problem. If I remove internet connectivity completely, then it eliminates the problem. Also we tested with SIMs from two different providers.

Comment: Perhaps Samsung is using SNTP or the equivalent to get the time. Could you put the device on a network segment behind some firewall that blocks outbound SNTP ports?